# Windows running python program using twitchio, windows gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitchio'

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to run a twitch bot, and it uses the twitchio module. Whenever I run the program in question I recieve back the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitchio' error.

The command I used to install the twitchio module was "py -m pip install -U twitchio", and I'm running python 3.11.3 and that's the only version I have installed.

The command I ran and recieved the original error from was "pipenv run python C:\path\to\program\bot.py", and the command was run in the admin windows command line. However, oddly enough when I run a program in VS code that just import modules it runs fine, and I tried putting a different module in front of the twitchio one and windows gave back an error for that module. So I'm thinking the problem is something with windows.

The biggest problem I'm finding is that I have the twitchio module installed, so I'm not really understaning what the problem is, does anyone have any ideas how I could fix this problem?

Comment: would you please add what prompts you ran in order to install twitchio ? Did you use the official and also version congruent documentation: https://twitchio.dev/en/latest/installing.html ?
What version of python are you running ? Do you know about having multiple versions of python installed ?

Comment: How, exactly, did you install the module?  Show us the exact command you typed to install it.  Also, tell us exactly how you run the code.  Are you using an IDE like PyCharm or VS Code, or running on the command line, or some other way?

Comment: Test this in the simple python prompt, and by typing: import twichio